# Vue3 datepicker: How to display the default calendar given for a specific month and year?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuepic-vue-datepicker

I am using [@vuepic/vue3datepicker](https://vue3datepicker.com/)  which automatically displays the current month's days when I use it:

```js
<template>
  <VueDatePicker v-model="date" inline></VueDatePicker>
</template>
```

[image]

But I am getting the month and year from an API, so I would like to display to the user the days of the related month and year, not the days of the current month.

Actually this goal is easy to achieve by:

```js
onMounted(() => {
  date.value = new Date(props.year, Number(props.month)-1, 1)
})
```

The problem is that I also need to use the [highlight](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/general-configuration/#highlight) prop (because I also get a list of other days of month/year couple which I need to highlight to the user), which thing means my `date` in `v-model="date"` should be an array:

```js
<template>
  <VueDatePicker v-model="date" :highlight="highlightedDates" />
</template>
```

So I am not sure how to overcome this.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: It's not clear what `highlight` prop has to do with v-model needing to be an array, but regardless:  `date.value = [new Date(props.year, Number(props.month)-1, 1)]` is now an array with 1 date.  I think you might need [multi-dates](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/modes/#multi-dates) prop as well.

Comment: You are right. You make me feel stupid :) @yoduh (*It's not clear what highlight prop has to do with v-model needing to be an array* : I get an error in the browser complaining about that)

Comment: Feel free to convert your comment to an answer, if you want @yoduh.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Answer posted.

Comment: there are several vue datepickers, but I did not see posts about this one, that is why I thought your comment would help others in the future too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no problem to put the `new Date()` value into an array of other `new Date()` values.  Here is an example of an array containing 1 date:

```js
date.value = [ new Date(props.year, Number(props.month)-1, 1) ]
```

You can manually push, slice, or do any other native Array functions as needed.  For the v-model in the template to work you may also need [multi-dates](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/modes/#multi-dates) prop as well.

```html
  <VueDatePicker v-model="date" inline multi-dates></VueDatePicker>
```